# prevent Sublime Text 2 from opening files as I type in file search

Tags: editor, preferences, sublimetext2

I like being able to search for any file by name in my project and open it, but I don't want Sublime Text 2 opening the files as I'm typing the name.  I only want it to open the file when I hit Enter/click its name in the results list.  There happen to be some huge files that it'll try to open just because the file name is similar to the name of the file I'm looking for, then the program hangs and it's faster to just Force Quit it rather than wait the 45s-1m for Sublime to start responding again.

How can I prevent Sublime Text 2 from opening files as I search for them?

Comment: I think that's a 'feature' called preview. Try disabling it.

Comment: @bvukelic I don't think that's the right setting, as the description in the default preferences file says `preview_on_click` is "Preview file contents when clicking on a file in the side bar. Double clicking or editing the preview will open the file and assign it a tab."  Or maybe I just found the wrong preference for what you're talking about.

Comment: This looks relevant, though:  http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/95775-disable-live-preview/

Comment: Yes, that's the 'preview' I was thinking of. Couldn't find a way to disable it, though. For me, it worked very well, until I started shoving all kinds of plugins into ST2. At some point, I remember it stopped being such a nice feature. But now in freshly installed ST2, it is as snappy as it gets.